# Getting managedObjectContext from AppDelegate

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to get the `managedObjectContext` from the **`AppDelegate`** on the mac platform (not iOS) to do some CoreData operations. As many answers here on SO already pointed out (although mostly for iOS) there are a couple of options like creating a singleton to access the managedObjectContext or adding a `managedObjectContext` property to every controller from which I want to access it.
I've done the latter but every time I try to create a managedObject based of some entity I get the following error: `+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity`

Here's what I have done so far:
ViewController.h:

```
@interface HitpointsTableViewConroller : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource> {
IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
NSMutableArray *list;
}

@property NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

Init method for that controller to get the `managedObjectContext`

```
- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    // get the managedObjectContext
    NSManagedObjectContext *currentContext = [[NSApp delegate]managedObjectContext];
    self.managedObjectContext = currentContext;

    hitpointsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

return self;
}
```

Method where I create a new instance of NSManagedObject:

```
- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender {
  // create new item
  Item *item = (Item *)[NSEntityDescription   
  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item"   
  inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

  // set defaults for that item
  [item setName:@"Coffee"];
  [item setPrice:2.99];

  // add hitpoint to list
   [list addObject:item];
   }
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: your property has no attributes. AFAIK, "atomic" is the default then, which would be bad for most objects.

Second: if you always get the MOC from the app-delegate, why assign it to a property? in your addItem-method, just get your MOC from the delegate instead of the property.

Third: if getting the MOC from the delegate still results in the nil-error, you obviously need to check your methods in the delegate.

(originally posted this as a comment, but since comments don't allow for paragraph-formatting, I reposted it as an answer)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! What would you recommend in this situation: - Always refer to the AppDelegate when getting the context with `NSManagedObjectContext *currentContext = [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext];` (like I've seen it people doing on iOS) or passing it as a reference to every (controller)object that needs it?

Comment: Depends on what are you doing. If you have a simple setup that uses only one context, getting it from the delegate is fine and saves you a lot of properties and some headache. However, if you start working with several (maybe parent-child-related) contexts on different threads, you should pass the correct context down. Be aware that all UI-related things have to happen in the same thread and thus need to use the same context. Of course, a combination of both is possible, too.